# Excel Python Saving Into New Directory

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I am trying to save an excel into a new directory. Lets say if someone on a different computer tries to run a code with reading an excel file. They won't be able to run the code on their computer because the directory is on my computer. I know everyone has an `F:\Users\`. How to automatically save excel file to other user's directory? Also will they be asked to resave the file every time they run the code Example: `Are you sure you want to replace file`? Is there a better way to do this?

```
xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application') # Running Excel
xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('I:\TPGeneral\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm')# Reading xlsm file
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath) # Opening file
xlApp.Run('csvfile2')# Running macro---- csvfile2 is the macro name. It is under the "csv" module in the VBA editor
wb.Save()
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: So, what is your question here?

Comment: How to automatically save excel file to other user's directory? Also will they be asked to resave the file every time they run the code? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an existing file to another directory you can use:

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(sourceFoldersPath + name, targetFolderPath + name)
```

Concerning the permissions look at the [warning in the doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shutil.html).
It fundamentally says: Depending on your os, some metadate gets lost.
EDIT: The warning talks about `shutil.copy()` and `shutil.copy2()`. Additionaly the doc string for `shutil.copyfile` states: "Copy the contents (no metadata) [...]"

Comment: like this: `from shutil import copyfile
copyfile('F:\Users\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm', 'F:\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm')`

Comment: as far as i can tell this should work. but to be safe: make shure your file isn't used anymore elsewhere.

Comment: I am getting Permission Denied Error Message

Comment: do you mean you can't copy it or you can't access the file after copying? and what error / exception do you get?

Comment: I got it to work, for some reason, it turned the file into a read-write file and it was giving me problems

Comment: for copying a file with `copyfile(...)` you don't have to open a file writer stream (in case you mean this). nevertheless: if my answer was helpfull for you, please consider accepting my answer or voting up.